# Python: How to replace an if statement that is always true or false, inside a for loop?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a for loop like the following:

```
flag = True
for i in range(100000):
    if flag:
        foo()
    else:
        bar()
```

The flag variable is set by a command line argument and stays the same for every loop. Is there any way to get rid of the costly if statement, other than having 2 different for loops?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
flag = True
func = foo if flag else bar

for i in range(100000):
    func()
```